# Scrapy OSI-approved license

Tags: scrapy

Wondering if Scrapy has/is an OSI-approved license? https://opensource.org/licenses

According to the [LICENSE](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/LICENSE) on Github it looks like it is the [BSD 3-clause License](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause) but I am hoping I could get clarification. I need to know as I am looking for a project for my academic course and need to contribute but must be OSI-approved to meet the requirements.

Comment: It’s unambiguously BSD, so why are you asking?

Comment: My instructor asked that I confirm that it's an OSI-approved license in order to use for my course. :/ I thought it was kind of annoying too, but I have to. The instructor said if I confirm it is approved I should try to contribute the actual statement of it being an OSI-approved license.

Comment: The BSD license does not require you to "contribute" anything...

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't explain that well. I am in an Open Source Software course. Part of the coursework is that we contribute or try to contribute to a project. A contribution includes adding to documentation. For example, it is confirmed that the license for Scrapy is an OSI-approved license then I could make a very small (suggestion) contribution to state Scrapy's license is BSD 3-clause License on the LICENSE page on Github. I guess it's painfully obvious but why not state it if it is OSI-approved?

Comment: As someone who maintains many open-source projects, I really don't appreciate contributions that amount to nothing more than minor tweaks to documentation. Remember that open-source projects are under no obligation to accept your contributions/PRs. Whoever designed or approved of your course did not think this through (and you should probably ask for a refund). If you want to make a meaningful contribution then submit a PR that addresses some long-standing open bug or feature-request.

Comment: "why not state it if it is OSI-approved?" - the same reason the Nutrition Facts label on grocery shopping sold and purchased in the US don't state if they're approved by the FDA's equivalent in Finland - or why Apple doesn't list every Android OS release that the iPhone can't run. The OSI is not a *pertinent* standards-setting body. What your instructor is doing is just creating [make-work](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make-work).